# Get Latest Artifact from JFrog - Artifactory OSS

Tags: artifactory

I'm using JFrog Artifactory OSS in a docker container. 
I want to download the latest version of an artifact. But it seems that it is not possible in OSS version.

Does anybody know a way to download the latest version of the artifact?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the [Latest Version API endpoint](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactLatestVersionSearchBasedonProperties) works only in Artifactory Pro.

Working with Maven repositories, you can use the `SNAPSHOT` support to get Artifactory to return you the latest artifact. 
Setting the Maven Snapshot behavior in repo settings to Unique, deploy the artifacts with `-SNAPSHOT` suffix. Artifactory will assign a unique version to those files internally, but you will always be able to retrieve the latest one using the `-SNAPSHOT` suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your fast answer. I forgot you tell my hole workflow.

I have a jenkins server, building, testing and deploying my stuff.

I want build a spring boot jar file with maven and deploy it to my repository(i use jfrog). This works perfect. In a next step i will create a docker image containing this jar file. So the in the image file ther must be a command to download the execuatbel jar from jfrog. So for this reason i have to know the latest version of the jar file.

I hope you could understand it, this is my first english question.

Thanks a lot for helping me !